# Add Account Identifier to Visualforce Community Site URL

Tags: visualforce, experience-cloud, digital-experience

I have created a community with the base URL https://devbox-apply-now.cs205.force.com/main. My requirement is to add an identifier such as acctid and customize the community accordingly with the Account.

eg : `https://devbox-apply-now.cs205.force.com/main?{*}acctid=0010e11001NfKpH{*}`

Can someone help me to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation that [Audiences](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.community_builder_page_visibilty_manage.htm&type=5) in Experience Cloud were designed for. Create audiences for each Account that your Users are tied to (via User --> ContactId --> AccountId) and from there you can assign different page layouts, different themes, and individually show or hide components with Audience Targeting.

There's no need to maintain a query string parameter in the URL.